# Measuring time with time.h?

Tags: c

I'm trying to measure time it takes to run a command using my own command interpreter, but is the time correct? When I run a command it says time much longer than expected:

```
miniShell>> pwd
/home/dac/.clion11/system/cmake/generated/c0a6fa89/c0a6fa89/Debug
Execution time 1828 ms
```

I'm using the `gettimeofday` as can be seen from the code. Isn't it wrong somewhere and should be changed so that the timing looks reasonable?

If I make a minimal example, then it looks and runs like this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long time;
    struct timeval time_start;
    struct timeval time_end;
    gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);
    printf("run program>> ");
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    time = (time_end.tv_sec-time_start.tv_sec)*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec-time_start.tv_usec;
    printf("Execution time %ld ms\n", time);    /*Print out the execution time*/
    return (0);
}
```

Then I run it

```
  /home/dac/.clion11/system/cmake/generated/c0a6fa89/c0a6fa89/Debug/oslab
    run program>> Execution time 14 ms

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

The above 14 ms seems reasonable, why is the time so long for my command?

Comment: you should look at the shell cmd 'time', which returns 3 times: the real time spent if you cumulate the processors time, the user time (the time you are actually calculating) and the time spent in kernel.

Comment: [TL;DR!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) Please narrow down the code to the problematic parts, or even better try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Something you should know by now.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We could find and fix the bug. I had mixed milliseconds with microseconds. Now I could use the solution in the answer and the timing now is reasonable. 2 milliseconds for running `pwd`. 0.7 millseconds for running `echo hello` and about 27 milliseconds for running `cowsay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute the time incorrectly. `tv_usec`, where the `u` stands for the Greek lowercase letter μ ("mu"), holds a number of microseconds.  Fix the formula this way:

```
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    time = (((time_end.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec) * 1000000LL) +
            time_end.tv_usec - time_start.tv_usec) / 1000;
    printf("Execution time %ld ms\n", time);    /* Print out the execution time*/
```

It is preferable to make the computation in 64 bits to avoid overflows if `long` is 32 bits and the elapsed time can exceed 40 minutes.

If you want to preserve the maximum precision, keep the computation in microseconds and print the number of milliseconds with a decimal point:

```
    gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
    time = (time_end.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
            time_end.tv_usec - time_start.tv_usec;
    printf("Execution time %ld.%03ld ms\n", time / 1000, time % 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! After making this change then my numbers are reasonable. 1 millisecond for running `ls` and about 50 milliseconds for running `cowsay`

Answer (score 3):

The tv_usec in struct timeval is a time in microseconds, not milliseconds.